# Determine the parameters of the transformer without any test

Tags: transformer

I have to make the equivalent circuit of a transformer like this image:

[image]

According to [this post,](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38422/transformers-parameters) I have to do some tests (open and short circuit,) but I can't so I'm trying to determine the transformer's parameter with the given information.

1. primary rating voltage: 300V
2. secondary rating voltage: 10V
3. transformer power capacity: 100VA
4. percentage impedance: 5%
5. efficiency: 98%
6. frequency: 100kHz
7. magnetizing current: 2% of primary rating current
8. core loss = copper loss

How can I determine a parameter of the transformer with this information?

---

### edit

Turns Ratio (Np/Ns) = Primary Rating Voltage / Secondary Rating Voltage = 300V / 10V = 30
h

Primary Rating Current (Ip) = Rated Power Capacity / Primary Rating

Voltage = 100VA / 300V ≈ 0.333A

Magnetizing Current(Im) = 2% of Ip = 0.02 * 0.333A ≈ 0.00666A

[image]

This is what I proceeded with, but I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Proceed from most simple to *stuck*, and tell exactly where you are stuck. Please add to your question your take on \$I_P\$ and copper losses.

Comment: primary rating + power rating => primary current. Mag current = 2% of primary => mag current => Xm. Solve those and post the results, then continue in that vein until you're stuck

Comment: I think "intermediate results" look good at [revision 3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/666627/3) - I'd use 102W and get 6.8 mA. Next, I'd make a bold assumption (*and state so*) that copper losses are the same on primary and secondary side. (I keep wondering whether I should assume primary voltage sinusoidal - 100 kHz doesn't spell *mains*.)